# Callback in jQuery wrapper function

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I have written a function that retrieves a html template, then binds data using jQuery.tmpl. I think it's fairly neat and tidy and encapsulates what I need and provides me a reusable function. My question however is can it be improved.

My main concern is what if the $.get method fails, and also how the callBack function is executed.

```
function Bind(templateURL, templateData, templateTarget, callBack){
var req = $.get(templateURL);
    req.success(function(templateHtml) { 
        $(templateTarget).html(''); //clear
        $(templateHtml).tmpl(templateData).appendTo(templateTarget); //add deal
    callBack();
    });
 }
```

Comment: i suggest change the function name to avoid confusing with Function.bind
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
and jQuery.bind function.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I'd pop this inside a namespace anyway though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the result of `tmpl()` directly to [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to clear your target container and append the new content at the same time. You can also chain the result of [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) into your `success` handler to avoid using a local variable:

```
function Bind(templateURL, templateData, templateTarget, callBack)
{
    $.get(templateURL).success(function(templateHtml) { 
        $(templateTarget).html($(templateHtml).tmpl(templateData));
        callBack();
    });
}
```

If `$.get()` fails, nothing will happen since you do not register an error handler. What that handler would do is up to you, but you might want to display an appropriate message in an alert box or somewhere on the page.

Your second concern is less clear. As it stands, `callBack` will only be called on success, and without arguments.

Comment: @hamczu, `callBack` is actually available in the scope of the `success` handler, because anonymous functions [close over](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29#JavaScript) local variables. And if you think about it, were `callBack` not accessible, neither would be `templateTarget` and `templateData` :)

Comment: Is there still a race condition risk when chaining the success/error/complete methods? 

The reason I asked the original question is I'm trying to shift people away from using UpdatePanels (.NET). And I'm trying to make it as easy as possible for them (though I still want them to understand how this all works).

Comment: @Jamie, I just double-checked and it appears I misread the docs: registering the handlers immediately only seems to be a convention, not a rule, and there can be no race condition since the `jqXHR` object supports deferred operation. Answer updated, sorry for the trouble :|

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.ajax to assign and error calback. ex:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({ url: "example.php" })
    .success(function() { alert("success"); })
    .error(function() { alert("error"); })
```

Check the api http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/